# Update current row using previous row

Tags: oracle, validation

The requirement that i have is i have to update the current row using previous row.Condition if previous row is null then it should pick the last value where it is not null. I have to create a stored procedure and update historical data set.Any help would be welcome.Database is Oracle

Comment: What do you mean by "if previous row is null"? Is there a specific column that is null? How is "previous" determined? Is it the previously inserted row or something else, e.g. based on a number in a column?

Comment: Please provide some sample input data and your expected output.

Comment: our process runs daily. Now for Tuesday run i have to check all the null values in different columns and update them with values from Monday's run.If Monday run value is not null for that particular column we have to go for Friday run and keep going till we find not null value.That column value would be used to update Tuesday Run value.

Comment: Input    
Run_Date PK_Column Date1 Date2         Date3
14-Dec-17 abcde 02-Jan-17 08-Jan-17 15-Jan-17
15-Dec-17 abcde null                 null                  null
output    
Run_Date PK_Column Date1 Date2 Date3
14-Dec-17 abcde 02-Jan-17 08-Jan-17 15-Jan-17
15-Dec-17 abcde 02-Jan-17 08-Jan-17 15-Jan-17

Answer (score 0):

You may collect into a temp table the last NOT NULL values and then, use them to update the current row.

or you can use a curosr where to collect last not null record from previous days and update the current dayu with it.

Best,

Comment: Probably the least performative way of doing anything.